# How to configure the envoy proxy for my go app?

Tags: grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I am trying to call from vue app via grpc to the go app as the follows:

[image]

Between them, it is an envoy proxy and is neccessary as described here https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web#2-run-the-server-and-proxy. The envoy proxy is running in the docker container, the vue and go app on localhost. The problem is, the vue app can not reach the go app, because I think, the envoy is running on different network than the go app. 
Envoy is configured as follows:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9000 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: identity_service
                  max_grpc_timeout: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - prefix: "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                max_age: "1728000"
                expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.cors
          - name: envoy.router
  clusters:
  - name: identity_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9090 }}]
```

What is wrong with the envoy configuration?

Comment: What's your docker networking set up like? I.e. do you have host networking enabled for envoy so 127.0.0.1 is your host localhost?

Comment: I am a beginner in envoy world and did not do any configuration. So I need an advice. My goal is, the communication between vue and go app.

Comment: Well easiest option would be to put the go app also in a container on same docker network as the envoy container, networking from container to host (your localhost) is more difficult and not all platforms support it from memory.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/network/ is good place to start on networking between containers